# In windows phone 7, How to make an event raise when user presses anywhere on the screen

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am new to windows phone 7 using silverlight.
I want that the user will be able to press anywhere on the screen, it will raise an event, and I will be able to know where on the screen the user pressed.

Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might not be able to add a click event to the main tag of a page but you can use `MouseLeftButtonUp` in the page tag.

Comment: It works in the simulator. However, when it will work on the real phone there is no mouse there, will it work the same way? ( sorry for the newbie question )

Comment: Mouse just means any input device

Answer (score 2):

Try by using the [Silverlight toolkit for Windows Phone 7](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).
If you need to capture the Tap event on the page, you've to use the services of the GestureListner class.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    x:Name="phoneApplicationPage" 
    x:Class="XXXXX"
    >
       <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <toolkit:GestureListener Tap="Page_Tap" />
       </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        .
        .
        .
```